# Compute $H_1([0,1], \{0,1\})$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In algebraic topology course, my teacher said that it was obvious, by considering the long exact sequence of the pair $([0,1], \{0,1\})$, that
$$H_k([0,1], \{0,1\}) \cong 
\begin{cases}
\mathbb Z & \text{if }  k = 1,\\
0 & \text{if } k > 1,
\end{cases}$$
where $H_k([0,1], \{0,1\})$ is the relative homology group of the pair $([0,1], \{0,1\})$. I do not see why this should be so obvious because by considering the long exacte sequence, we get
$$0 = H_1([0,1]) \to H_1([0,1], \{0,1\}) \to H_0(\{0,1\})\cong \mathbb Z^2 \to H_0([0,1]) \cong \mathbb Z \to H_0([0,1], \{0,1\}) \to 0.$$
How should we be able to conclude $H_1([0,1], \{0,1\})\cong \mathbb Z$?

Comment: You need to compute the map $H_0(\{0,1\})\simeq\mathbb{Z}^2\to H_0([0,1])\simeq\mathbb{Z}$ (by the way, there is a typo in your long exact sequence, this should be the $H_0$ of $\{0,1\}$ instead of  the $H_1$). Now $H_1([0,1],\{0,1\})$ is just the kernel of this map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The map $c : [0,1] \to \{0,1\}, c(x) = 0$, has the property $i \circ c \simeq id$, where $i :  \{0,1\} \hookrightarrow [0,1]$.